# std::array and bytes reading

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, stdarray

I have read a lot of things about not using C-style in C++, but instead use containers like std::array, std::vector or std::string.

Now I am trying to read and write small binary files with file streams and store it in std::array.

It looks like the read and write method from std::fstream can work only with C-style arrays...

So this is what I think about:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::fstream testFile, outTestFile;
    testFile.open("D:/mc_svr/another/t/world/region/r.0.0.mca", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary);
    outTestFile.open("D:/mc_svr/another/t/world/region/xyz.xyz", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::binary);

    std::array<byte_t, 8192> testArray;

    testFile.read((char*) &testArray, 8192);
    outTestFile.write((char*) &testArray, 8192);

    testFile.close();
    outTestFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

byte_t is just a

```
typedef char byte_t;
```

It works. But it is this the good way to do it ? If no, what are the other ways to do it ? Should I use byte_t [] instead ?

Comment: That code you show most definitely doesn't work, at least not as you expect it to. When you do e.g. `outTestFile.write((char*) &testArray, 8192);` you write the `testArray` *object* and not the actual array that `testArray` wraps. And the read and write functions can read and write arbitrary data, it doesn't have to be C-style arrays (as you see form your faulty code). For example, to write a single integer value you can do e.g. `outTestFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&intVariable))`

Comment: Well, on my machine works ok, but this is why I asked : to be sure. Thank you for your reply.

EDIT: Yes, I know how to read and write binary another types of data (most numbers).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg since std::array probably has no other members except data, program will work as expected. Though it is a bad idea to do so in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::array::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data):

```
testFile.read(testArray.data(), testArray.size());
outTestFile.write(testArray.data(), testArray.size());
```

Note the use of `.size()` instead of the magic number.

Also you don't need to `.close()` your files. The `fstream` destructor will do that for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think sometimes I really need to use some numbers, especially when I don't write the entire array. I will keep in mind the fstream destructor do all my work for me. Thanks !

Comment: Worth remembering, though, that the close will only happen when the destructor is activated, i.e. when it goes out of scope; I've seen an issue where someone relied on that fact initially, then later added code that read a file that hadn't been explicitly closed after being written.